# CSS transition not working with transform: translate

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-transitions

How can I realize a smooth transition for my mobile menu?

The `transform` property is working, but I want it to happen slowly..

My Sass looks like this

```
  .mobile-nav
   display: none
   position: relative
   width: 100%
   background: $white
   padding: 30px 0 20px
   transform: translateY(-100%)

    @media (max-width: 775px)
     .mobile-nav.is-o
      display: block
      transform: translateY(0%)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main obstacle you're facing is that the `display` property is not animatable.

Like a light switch, `display: none` is off and `display: block` is on. There's no middle ground, no fade effects, no CSS transitions.

However, there are multiple other properties you can use for transitions. Among them:

- `height`
- `opacity`
- `z-index`
- `background-color`

Here's an example:

```css
.mobile-nav-toggle {
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mobile-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, opacity 0s 1s, background-color 0s 2s;
}
.mobile-nav-toggle:hover + .mobile-nav {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav-toggle">&#9776;</div>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

References:

- [Full list of animatable properties in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties-)
- [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331353/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

I personally use **opacity** combined with **visibility** to achieve fade effect like I would like for whole element. Remember to manipulate **z-index**, so you "hidden" object won't be clickable when dissapeared.

Comment: With `opacity` and `z-index`, why is `visibility` needed?

Comment: It's a safe play for some rare cases, where element is under element with no background and/or it's bigger than it.